# Optical shift in a view from above

Tags: homework-and-exercises, optics, refraction, geometric-optics

In the following case, two objects are moving to each other from two different media:
[image]

Apparently, the distance between the two, at this moment, is not the sum of $6$ and $0.8$, but involves dividing one by the refractive index of water.

Why is this necessary? Shouldn't the apparent and real depth be the same when the object and viewer are in the same vertical line?

Comment: Do you mean *distance* or *optical distance*? If I have a container, which is 1m in length, it's length does not change if we fill it with water? However, if we use a measurement device, which uses e.g. the time of flight of a reflected light beam, we have to consider the index of refraction. So I reckon that your question is assuming a context, which is not stated explicitly.

Comment: The question refers to the distances measured from the objects, as in 'height of B, as observed from F', and vice versa.

Comment: I've removed a number of comments that were attempting to answer the question and/or responses to them. Please keep in mind that comments should be used for suggesting improvements and requesting clarification on the question, not for answering.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Coin: one with water, one without]

So, I took this pictures 5 mins ago with my cellphone camera. Distance to the coin is the same, i.e. from the rim of the glass. One glass is full of water, the other has nothing in it. I think you can even guess which one has water.
Which one looks closer?

Yes, it is "un-intuitive" when talking about straight lines in optics. However, whatever you measure objectively will always tell you that the coin "is closer". Phase is what is important in a straight line, and the objective value that is measurable. And phase travels at the speed of light in that medium!

In a simple straight line, you need to account with refractive index. With a real image (e.g. the image of a coin), diffraction (and maybe you can say refraction, if you decide to trace all the rays from the edge of the coin) will make sure the object looks closer.

This is all oversimplified, but sometimes they are enough to understand simple phenomena.

Comment: Of course that if we reverse this experiment (i.e. I am inside the water and look at a coin in air). The coin will look smaller. And the phase will make it look like the coin is "further" (you need to consider the phase relative to the medium where you are measuring in, i.e. whats the difference in phase if the coin was only in water, or air/water for same distance in the case of measuring inside water.)